# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-map-gl-geocoder'

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Hi I am trying to use Mapbox geocoder for my react-project. I am always getting those two errors.

Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-map-gl-geocoder'. 'Git/react-excercises/node_modules/react-map-gl-geocoder/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-map-gl-geocoder` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-map-gl-geocoder';`ts(7016)

./node_modules/react-map-gl-geocoder/dist/index.m.js
Attempted import error: 'FlyToInterpolator' is not exported from 'react-map-gl' (imported as 'r').

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-excercises",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "mapbox": "^1.0.0-beta10",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.7.0",
    "mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^2.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-map-gl": "^7.0.9",
    "react-map-gl-geocoder": "^2.2.0",
    "react-mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^1.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "reactstrap": "^9.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: So did you try what the error recommended? Install the types:
`npm i --save-dev @types/react-map-gl-geocoder`